# What permutations of matrix entries do row and column transpositions generate?

Tags: matrices, permutations

Let $M$ be a square matrix. By transposing rows and columns, can we get any permutation of the entries of $M?$ If we can't, which permutations are generated?

Comment: No. Being (or not) in the same row (or column) is preserved.

Comment: @xavierm02 we can transpose _both_ columns and rows. If we transpose the first row with the second row and then the first column with the second column, then $M_{11}$ becomes $M_{22}$.

Comment: You can't get from $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preserving column and row members will be the only obstruction (i.e. if $a$ and $b$ are in the same row originally they will be in the same row after the transformation).  So there are only $(n!)^2$ possible rearrangements via row/column transpositions, out of $(n^2)!$ possible rearrangements of the $n^2$ entries.  Your permutations are elements of $S^n \times S^n$, the cartesian product of the permutation group on $n$ letters.  For $$(\sigma, \tau) \in S^n \times S^n$$ we have $$ (a_{ij}) \mapsto (a_{\sigma(i) \tau(j)}).$$

Comment: An interesting consequence of your statement is that row permutations and column permutations commute.

Comment: Yes, that is interesting.  I just realized that it is straightforward from the standpoint of performing the transpositions with elementary matrices, i.e. swapping rows 1 and 2 by multiplying on the left by $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right].$$
In this setting, all row permutations correspond to multiplying on the left by a product of elementary matrices, while column permutations are done by multiplying on the right by elementary matrices.  Since matrix multiplication is associative, order of multiplication cannot change our answer.