# Can you make up any matrix permutation with switching rows, columns, and transposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If I have a matrix of an arbitrary size, can I transform it into any matrix of same size that uses same elements using only switching rows/columns, and transposition (or transposition but using the other diagonal)? I looked into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017027/what-permutations-of-matrix-entries-do-row-and-column-transpositions-generate) answer, but it only says that it's impossible without transposing the matrix.

Comment: Please clarify (possibly with an example) what do you mean with a ***transposition***.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti It's the matrix transpose.

Comment: @Arthur, OK, thanks, I though it was some swap of elements inside the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still impossible to go from, for instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, because your operations don't change whether your matrix is invertible. In fact, they don't change the determinant at all except perhaps a sign change.

More concretely, if two element are on the same row or column, no matter what combination of operations you do, they still share either row or column afterwards.

Comment: What operations could we add to make a complete system of operations?

Comment: @RomaValcer I believe something as simple as swapping the first and second element in the first row is enough.